# XSLT: Combine 2 XML files to one

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 2 xml files:

File1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offer file_format="IOF" generated="2017-08-04 05:27:56"  version="2.5" extensions="no"><products xmlns:iaiext="http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml">
    <product id="1356">
        <name>Name1</name>
    </product>
    <product id="1357">
        <name>Name2</name>
    </product>
</products>
</offer>
```

And File2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offer file_format="IOF" generated="2017-08-04 05:27:56"  version="2.5" extensions="no">
    <products xmlns:iaiext="http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml">
        <product id="1356">
            <avail>True</avail>
        </product>
        <product id="1357">
           <avail>False</avail>
        </product>
    </products>
</offer>
```

I want get this:

```
<product id="1356">
    <name>Name1</name>
    <avail>True</avail>
</product>
<product id="1357">
    <name>Name2</name>
    <avail>False</avail>
</product>
```

How can I do this? When I'm in a loop on 'name' it reads wrong to 'avail'.

My xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSLT/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="offer/products/product">
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            <xsl:value-of select="document('File2.xml')/offer/products/product/avail"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried to use a variable and the result was the same.

Comment: Can  you edit your question to show the XSLT you have currently tried? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I add my xslt code.

Comment: Do you want to also remove the namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `xsl:copy` instead of `xsl:value-of` of here, as you want to copy the whole node, rather than just the text value.

Additionally, when you select from "file2.xml" you need to specify the current product id in the condition.

Also note, the namespace URI you have shown for the xsl prefix is wrong. It should be "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="offer/products/product">
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:copy-of select="@*|name" />
               <xsl:copy-of select="document('File2.xml')/offer/products/product[@id = current()/@id]/avail"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an XSLT-1.0 solution also removing the namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:iaiext="http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="second" select="document('File2.xml')/offer/products" /> 

    <!-- copy elements without namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove offer element -->
    <xsl:template match="offer">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- reconstruct 'product' element -->
    <xsl:template match="product">
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
      <xsl:element name="product">        <!-- clear the namespace -->
        <name><xsl:value-of select="name" /></name>
        <avail><xsl:value-of select="$second/product[@id=$id]/avail"/></avail>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is (with a root element 'products'):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Name1</name>
        <avail>True</avail>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Name2</name>
        <avail>False</avail>
    </product>
</products>
```